# Update one table based upon SUM(values) in another table on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update

I can't seem to find out how to do this and not sure exactly how to search for it!

I have a table `[MASTER]`:

```
ID varchar(6)
CCY varchar(3)
Val1 decimal(20,5)
Val2 decimal(20,5)
FOO decimal(20,5)
```

and another table `[FOOS]`

```
ID varchar(6)
CCY varchar(3)
Val decimal(20,5)
```

`MASTER` contains one row per ID/CCY composite key (not sure if thats correct term) e.g.

```
ABCDEF GBP 200.00 100.00 null
ABCDEF EUR 400.00 150.00 null
ZYXWVU GBP 300.00 200.00 null
ZYXWVU EUR 400.00 200.00 null
```

`FOOS` contains multiple rows and DOES NOT contain a row for every `MASTER` e.g.

```
ABCDEF GBP 50.00
ABCDEF GBP 51.00
ABCDEF GBP 150.00
ZYXWVU GBP 100.00
ZYXWVU EUR 200.00
ZYXWVU EUR 400.00
```

I'd like to run a query to update only matching `MASTER` rows with `SUM(FOOS.Val)`. e.g.

```
ABCDEF GBP 200.00 100.00 251.00
ABCDEF EUR 400.00 150.00 null
ZYXWVU GBP 300.00 200.00 100.00
ZYXWVU EUR 400.00 200.00 600.00
```

...but although I've tried a numer of options (`where exists`, `inner join`) I can't seem to be able to either link to a single `MASTER` or do the `SUM(...)`

Comment: Master table contains one row per ID/CCY. And you want to update Master with the SUM for matching ID/CCY. Is that correct? Why not you do a group by on ID/CCY on Foo, then update Master using that first query as a nested query?

Comment: There goes the answer Mahmood has provided you :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
UPDATE m
SET m.Foo = f.valsum
FROM [MASTER] m
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT ID, CCY, SUM(val) valsum
  FROM Foos
  GROUP BY  ID, CCY 
) f ON m.ID = f.ID AND m.CCY  = f.CCY;
```

Answer (score 9):

With postgres, I had to adjust the solution with this to work for me:

```
UPDATE [MASTER] m
SET Foo = f.valsum
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, CCY, SUM(val) valsum
  FROM Foos
  GROUP BY  ID, CCY 
) f
WHERE m.ID = f.ID AND m.CCY = f.CCY;
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE accounts SET (contact_last_name, contact_first_name) =
    (SELECT last_name, first_name FROM salesmen
     WHERE salesmen.id = accounts.sales_id);

update orders 
set amount =
(select sum(item_quantity) from order_items 
where orders.id = order_items.order_id);